# Reading data from delimted string to create a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a string:

```
x|y|z;x|y|z;x|y|z;x|y|z;
```

I have replaced actual values with x, y & z

It is delimited by `;` and then `|`

What I'd like to have is

```
<select>
    <option>x z</option>
    <option>x z</option>
    <option>x z</option>
    <option>x z</option>
</select>
```

I do not need to get the `y` value.

No clue how to do this! Any ideas would be great! Thanks.

Comment: So you want to remove all instances of |y then split on ; and replace a | with a space?

Comment: If `y` has a fixed value. Just split with `| y |`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first want to split the string on `;` characters so that you have an array of xyz combinations:

```
var arr = str.split(";");
arr.pop(); // remove the last item:
           // your example has a trailing `;` which adds an empty item
```

You then want to split each combination on `|` characters so as to get the separate xyz values. Then you can use those values to create an `<option>` element.

```
// loop the array
$.each(arr, function() {
  var values = this.split("|");
  // ignore values[1], that's the y value
  $("<option>").text(values[0] + " " + values[2]).appendTo("select");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/bfRyW/
Hope it helps!

```
var string = 'x|y|z;x|y|z;x|y|z;x|y|z;';

var split1 = string.split(';');
split1.pop();

$.each(split1,function(index,value){
    var a = value.split('|');
    $('select').append('<option>'+a[0]+' '+a[2]+'</option>');
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

A POJS solution using one regular expression to split on both `|y|` and `;` is:

```
function genSelect(s) {
  var arr = s.split(/\|y\||;/);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  var t;

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    t = arr[i] + ' ' + arr[++i];
    sel.appendChild(new Option(t, t));
  }

  return sel;
}
```

Comment: `y` is not actually 'y', i have replace the original value.